# Simple printf(%s) Code not running as expected

Tags: arrays, c, char, printf

I was reading from a file and writing it into an char* but the chars were not beeing saved after the array[96]. So I decided to run a simple check with this code:

```
int main(void){
    char array[5];
    memset(array, 0, sizeof(array));
    array[1] = 'A';
    array[2] = '\0';
    printf("\n---%s---\n", array);
    return 0;
}
```

I would expect ---A--- to be printed into the console, but the A is missing. Am I missing something?

Comment: Array indexes start at `0`; `array[0]` is a null byte so the `printf()` prints an empty string.  Use `array[0] = 'A';` — there's no need to set `array[1]` since the `memset()` call did that.  (Incidentally, the question title is misguided now — the program is running properly and producing the correct output.  It's merely that your expectations don't match the reality of the code.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The array index should start from 0. As Jonathan answered in the above comment, no need to set the terminator `array[1] = '\0';` since the array already got memset to 0. So the final code snippet will look like.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void){
    char array[5];
    memset(array, 0, sizeof(array));
    array[0] = 'A';
    printf("\n---%s---\n", array);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Dropped the terminator assignment. Good. Could also use `char array[5] = { 0 };` and drop the `memset()`, too... Just a suggestion.

Comment: @Fe2O3: the initializer could even be `char array[5] = "A";` (with or without braces) too, but that is probably subverting the intent of the question.